# Stix/Stix2 with amsmath/amsfonts: \lvert, \rvert not rendering properly

Tags: symbols, stix

I'm trying to use the stix2 package, but for some reason it isn't rendering vertical bars (e.g., absolute value, etc.) using `\lvert` and `\rvert` correctly.

Using:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\begin{equation*}
    y = \lvert x \rvert
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

gives me this:

[image]

I'm using Overleaf if that matters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your document compiles fine for me, both on my computer and on Overleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I just answered my own question. The solution for me was to load the stix2 package **after** amsmath, as in

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix2} %load this *after* amsmath

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\begin{equation*}
    y = \lvert x \rvert
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, `stix2` already contains the symbols covered by `amsfonts`. So technically you should only load one of the two. Either `stix2` or `amsfonts`, but not both.